# Delphi 2009 - res file is not recreated

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I'Ve just created a small application with a toolbar, some toolbar buttons and an TPngImageList.
I have saved the project and compiled it.

Now I've deleted the .res file in the project folder.
When I now open the project in the IDE, delphi says "Res file could not be found. New created".
But after that, I can't find the new created res file in my project folder. (In other words: it isn't there!)
Why?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably you know, but to make sure: Note you should not delete the .RES file; it contains some information that is not in the project source files (including the project icon).

Comment: It's created in memory, not saved to disk until you save the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new project, Project1.dpr, and saved it in a new, empty, directory. Then I removed Project1.res, and opened the project. Delphi 2009 said

```
[Window Title]
Warning

[Content]
Cannot find resource file: C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\test2\Project1.res.  Recreated.

[OK]
```

and when I then *saved* the project, the Project1.res file was recreated. If I close the project without saving, no Project1.res file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .dproj file and change

```
<SkipResGeneration>true</SkipResGeneration>
```

to

```
<SkipResGeneration>false</SkipResGeneration>
```

if it is present.